# Bounded sets are relatively compact in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I know that every closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact (like $[a,b]$)

so i can conclude that every bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ is relatively compact, by contradiction i say that let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded set but not relatively compact it means that $\overline{A}$ is not compact, but $\overline{A}$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ so it is compact, contradiction.

My question is if $A$ is bounded, why $\overline{A}$ still bounded ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is bounded this means there is some $R > 0$ such that $d(x,y) \le R$ for all $x,y \in  A$. But the same then holds for $\overline{A}$ as well. This can for instance be seen as follows: pick $p \in A$, then all members of $A$ are in the closed ball $D(p,R) = \{x \in X: d(x,p) \le R \}$. So $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{D(p,R)} = D(p,R)$ as well.

So If $A$ is bounded, $\overline{A}$ is bounded (see above) and closed (by definition), so if we are in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\overline{A}$ is compact by Heine-Borel.

Answer (score 0):

Since A is bounded, it has a supremum and infimum. But  $\sup A=\sup \bar {A} $ and $\inf A=\inf \bar {A}$. Hence $\bar A $ is bounded.

To see why this claim is true. Suppose $\sup \bar {A} $ is bigger than $\sup A $ by $ \epsilon$. Since $\bar {A} $ is closed,  $\sup\bar {A}\in \bar {A} $. Now the ball of radius $\epsilon/2 $ around this point will intersect $ A $, which is a contradiction, since then $ A $ contains an element bigger than its supremum. The argument for the infimum is similar.

Answer (score 0):

As $A$
  is bounded, we have $A\subset\bar{\mathcal{B}}\left(0,M\right)$
  for a certain $0<M<+\infty$
 . Since $\bar{A}$
  is the smallest closed set that contains $A$
 , thus we must have $\bar{A}\subseteq\bar{\mathcal{B}}\left(0,M\right)$
  and then $\bar{A}$
  is bounded.

Comment: This is true for $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ that all ?

Comment: This is true for any metric space : the distance between $A$ and $\bar{A}$ is $0$ so if one is bounded, then the other is. The above ball $\bar{\mathcal{B}}\left(0,M\right)$ is the ball in your metric space ; for the case of $\mathbb{R}$ , you have $\bar{\mathcal{B}}\left(0,M\right)=\left[-M,M\right]$ .

Comment: Can we genereise this for Hausdorff space ? a question please are finite sets closed in a Hausdorff space ?

Comment: I am not sure to understand Hausdorff space : I know the Hausdorff distance which provides a metric space structure (and then, the above result holds - it holds for any metric space), or I know the Hausdorff topological spaces, but here, the notion of distance is uncertain (depends on the fact that your topology is metrisable or not). I am not sure to answer to your question...

Comment: by Hausdorff space i mean a separated space $E$ is separrated if $\forall x,y\in E, \exists U\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\in \mathcal{V}_y, U\cap V\neq \emptyset$

Comment: I think you wanted to mean “for all $x\neq y$ in $E$ , there are two neighbourhoods $\mathcal{V}_{x}$ and $\mathcal{V}_{y}$ of $x$ and $y$ respectivelysuch that $x\in\mathcal{V}_{x}$ and $y\in\mathcal{V}_{y}$ and $\mathcal{V}_{x}\cap\mathcal{V}_{y}=\emptyset$" .Here, $E$ is topological space, and the above argumentation does not hold. A finite set is not necessarily closed : take the discret topology on $E$ to see that each singleton is open and closed (and contains of course only one element of $E$, so is finite).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space

Comment: Ok I misundertood your notations. So in Hausdorff spaces, there is not distance (not necessarily), so I am not sure that your question holds in these spaces : what "finite" means now ? if it means that your set contains a finite number of elements, then this set is the reunion of all singletons that it contains, and is closed if the singletons are closed for your topology.

Comment: can you see this please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158707/exercise-on-topology-not-separated-but-satisfy-the-borel-lebesgue-property

Answer (score 0):

Recall what bounded means: When $A$ is bounded, there exists an open interval $(x_0-\delta;x_0+\delta)$ that contains $A$. Then the corresponding closed interval $[x_0-\delta;x_0+\delta]$ also contains $A$, and since the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, the closure of $A$ will be contained in the interval $[x_0-\delta;x_0+\delta]$. But then the closure of $A$ is also contained in the open interval $(x_0-2\delta;x_0+2\delta)$, which makes the closure of $A$ bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is bounded so $|x-y|\leq M$ for $x,y \in A$. If $\overline A$ is not bounded then there is a $z\in \overline A$ such that $dist(z,A)>0$. But $z\in \overline A$ means $dist(z,A)=0$. Contradiction.