# Exercise On topology not separated but satisfy the Borel-Lebesgue property

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have a set $E\neq \emptyset $ with the cofinite topology.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness

The question is if $E$ is infinite prove that is not separated but it satify the Borel-Lebesgue property.

We say that $E$ is separated if $\forall x,y\in E, \exists U\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\in\mathcal{V}_y, U\cap V=\emptyset $

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space

How to find $x,y\in E$ such that all the neighborhoods are not disjoint, i.e how to prove that $E$ is not separated?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the Borel-Lebesgue property? separated is normally called Hausdorff. I suppose you're French then (separée)?

Comment: yes in French it is "séparé" http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compacit%C3%A9_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29#Axiome_de_Borel-Lebesgue_et_d.C3.A9finition_g.C3.A9n.C3.A9rale_des_compacts

Comment: But know i just want to know why $E$ is separated (séparée)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any two points will do to show that $E$ is not Hausdorff (or separated). Take any $x \neq y$ in $E$. Let $U_x$ be any open neighbourhood of $x$ in $E$, and $U_y$ be any open neighbourhood of $y$. Then $E \setminus U_x$ is finite and $E \setminus U_y$ is finite, so their union is finite as well. The set $E \setminus ((E \setminus U_x) \cup (E \setminus U_y))$, is infinite as $E$ is infinite. But that set is just $U_x \cap U_y$ by de Morgan, so the intersection of $U_x$ and $U_y$ is non-empty.

So any two non-empty open sets of $E$ intersect (in an infinite set). This shows that $E$ is not Hausdorff in a strong way, but also that $E$ is connected, e.g.

Comment: I don't understand $U_x\cap U_y$ is non-empty sorry can you explain me more

Comment: @Vrouvrou $U_x \cap U_y = E \setminus ( ( E \setminus U_x) \cup (E \setminus U_y))$ as I said.

Comment: yes and then ? i don't see

Comment: The last set is a difference of an infinite set $E$ and the union of two finite sets. If you remove two finite sets from an infinite set, we are left with an infinite set (of the same cardinality).

Comment: if X is finite and E infinte then $E\setminus X$ can be finite !

Comment: No, it cannot. Give an example??

Comment: i don't know an example

Comment: If $X \subset E$ is finite and $E$ is infinite, then suppose $E \setminus X$ were finite. Then $E = (E \setminus X) \cup X$ would be a union of two finite sets, so finite. And $E$ is infinite so contradiction: $E \setminus X$ is infinite.

Comment: OK thank you as $U_x\cap U_y$ is infinite so authomatically it is nonempty

Comment: After that, in order to prove that $E$ satisfy the borel-Lebesgue i have the answer and it says "if $E\subset \cup_{i\in I}A_i$ ($A_i$ are open) then for each $i\in I$ $E\setminus A_i$ is finite i.e $E\setminus A_i=\cup_{k=1}^N \{x_k\}\subset \cup_{i\in I} A_i$ i don't understand why $E\setminus A_i$ still in $\cup A_i$ ?

Comment: If $E$ is a subset of it, then any subset as well.

Comment: Please i have an other question is the sub cover must be open ? because $C_{E}A_i$ is closed in $E$ and we say that $E=C_{E} A_i \cup A_i$ so $E$ satisfy the borel -Lebesgue property ?

Comment: Suppose we have a cover of open sets $A_i$ of $X$. Take any fixed $A_{i_0}$. Then $X \setminus A_{i_0}$ is finite. So we need finitely many more $A_i$ to cover those, plus $A_{i_0}$ to have a finite subcover. Done.

Comment: so we don't need an open finite subcover juste a finite sub cover from $(A_i)_{i\in I}$

Comment: right ?????????

Comment: Yes, a finite subcover for any open cover of $X$